# Example for using Guice with Endpoints Frameworks for App Engine version 2

Tags: java, google-app-engine, guice, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

Does anyone know a good example for using Guice with the new Google Endpoints Frameworks for App Engine Version 2.

In the Documentation

[Migrating to Endpoints Frameworks for App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/legacy/v1/java/migrating)

Guice is mentioned at the end of the docu. But i am missing a full example with web.xml, appengine-web.xml, Module class and Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `endpoints-framework-guice` as a dependency.
2. Add an instance of `EndpointsModule` to your `GuiceFilter`.
3. Additionally bind `GuiceFilter` to `/_ah/api/*` in `web.xml` to work around a legacy URL resolution issue.

Comment: Do you have some sample code for the web.xml, GuiceFIlter and EndpointsModule?

Does this work for Endpoints Framework:
https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ServletModule

Comment: `EndpointsModule` _is_ a `ServletModule`. So yes, they work together.

Answer (score 0):

Please review the [Using Guice with Endpoints Frameworks](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/using-guice) guide.

The example demonstrates how to use Endpoints Framework v2 with Guice.

Comment: seems to work, but now i have a new problem enhancing my JDO DB Classes.